# Mapbox zoom to current location (Pokemon go like zoom functionality)

Tags: javascript, typescript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

i'am trying to create a map like the one in 'Pokemon go'.
Now i want to create the zoom functionality the same way 'Pokemon go' did that.

My intention is when a user zooms it zooms in and out of the users current position, any idea's how to accomplish this with MapBox?

I have been trying search for something like this, but with no success yet.

My current map:

```js
this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'game_map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
            center: [5.348291, 52.151742],
            zoom: 17,
            pitch: 60,
            bearing: -60,
            antialias: true
        });
```

Edit:
I want to make a Pokemon go like map. So when the user zooms in, the camera needs to zoom to the users current position. And the user must not be able to move the camera only zoom in/out and rotate the camera. And i want so that when the user zooms in the pitch and bearing of the camera changes (in MapBoxgl js).

Comment: Looks like this feature was inplemented: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/3876 From this pull request it looks like you need to pass the options like `{ 
  zoom: 17,
  touchZoomRotate: {around: "center"},
  scrollZoom: {around: "center"},
 }`

Comment: Okay, thanks it works!

Comment: And do you if there is a property to change the pitch on zoom?

Comment: One thing, on pc it stays in the center, but on mobile you can move around.

Comment: It might be helpful to explain what "zoom functionality the same way 'Pokemon go' did that" means.

Comment: Do you mean lock the camera to always be centred on the user location?

Comment: Yes i do, i want to have the camera always centered to the users location.

Comment: I edited my post.